# Prevent custom control event from firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, treeview, controls

I have a custom control that inherits from [`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In this `CustomTreeView`, I handle the `OnNodeMouseClick` event to perform some process before changing the  `node.Checked` state as the user would expect it:

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView {
    // Constructor...

    protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
       base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);

       // Do something...

       e.Node.Checked = !e.Node.Checked;
    }
}
```

My problem is when the developer subscribes to the `AfterCheck` event on a `CustomTreeView`, the value of `e.Action` is always [`TreeViewAction.Unknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewaction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (because the checked state of the node is changed in the code), whereas the developer is waiting for `TreeViewAction.ByMouse`:

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    private void customTreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
        // e.Action == TreeViewAction.Unknown
        // [developer] The user clicked on the node, it should be 
        //             TreeViewAction.ByMouse!?
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is disable the `AfterCheck` event from firing and call it myself in my `CustomTreeView` class, that way I would be able to pass parameters with `TreeViewAction` equal to `ByMouse`. Something like that:

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView {
    // Constructor...

    protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
       base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);

       // Do something...

       // Prevent all AfterCheck events from firing, just for a moment
       // ??

       e.Node.Checked = !e.Node.Checked;

       // Allow AfterCheck events to fire
       // ??

       // Call myself the AfterCheck event
       base.OnAfterCheck(new TreeViewEventArgs(e.Node, TreeViewAction.ByMouse));
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just override `OnAfterCheck` in `CustomTreeView` and it will work like you intend.

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView {

    protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
       base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);

       // your stuff

       // Call myself the AfterCheck event
       base.OnAfterCheck(new TreeViewEventArgs(e.Node, TreeViewAction.ByMouse));
    }

    protected override void OnAfterCheck(TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
       // do nothing   
    }
}
```

---

[image]